# Watch Complication causes crash with dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CLKFullColorImageProvider

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

I'm getting this error `dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CLKFullColorImageProvider` in watchOS 4 but not in watchOS 5, I believe it's related to my complication code below but can't figure out why...as far as I can tell the compiler shouldn't be looking for `CLKFullColorImageProvider` as I've blocked that off with `if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *)`

```
class Complication: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {
    func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            if complication.family == .circularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Circular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .utilitarianSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Utilitarian") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .modularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Modular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .graphicCircular {
                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "GraphicCircular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .graphicBezel {
                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "GraphicBezel") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .graphicCorner {
                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerCircularImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "GraphicCorner") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else {

                handler(nil)

            }
        } else {

            if complication.family == .circularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Circular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .utilitarianSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Utilitarian") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .modularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Modular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else {

                handler(nil)

            }
        }
    }

    func getSupportedTimeTravelDirections(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void) {
        handler([])
    }
    func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            if complication.family == .circularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Circular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                handler(template)

            } else if complication.family == .utilitarianSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Utilitarian") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                handler(template)

            } else if complication.family == .modularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Modular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                handler(template)

            } else if complication.family == .graphicCircular {
                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "GraphicCircular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
                handler(template)

            } else if complication.family == .graphicBezel {
                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "GraphicBezel") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                handler(template)

            } else if complication.family == .graphicCorner {
                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerCircularImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "GraphicCorner") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
                handler(template)

            } else {

                handler(nil)

            }
        } else {
            if complication.family == .circularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Circular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                handler(template)

            } else if complication.family == .utilitarianSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Utilitarian") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                handler(template)

            } else if complication.family == .modularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Modular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                handler(template)

            } else {

                handler(nil)

            }
        }


    }







}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You and I encountered this issue at the same time.  From this page:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108598

Add `ClockKit.framework` as *optional* in the `Link Binary With Libraries` phase of your watch extension.  This took care of my issue right away.